# How to manage survivorship bias in conversion metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I am trying to understand diminishing returns on additional advertising. Basically, does the 2nd ad convert worse than the 1st, etc. I'm struggling with thinking about how to deal with the survivorship bias, because if a user converts, then they will stop seeing additional ads.

Are there ways to manage these biases? Ideally, I'm interested in modeling the likelihood of conversion given some demo factors and how many ads they've received so far.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach is the model conversion is [survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis). In this case, time-to-event would be how many ads until they convert.